# Bulk HIT Creation through Template

Tags: r, mechanicalturk

```
    library(MTurkR)
    options(MTurkR.sandbox = TRUE)
    credentials(keypair=c("XXXXXX","XXXXXX"))
    AccountBalance()
    #BulkCreateFromTemplate
    temp <- system.file("template.html", package = "MTurkR")
    a <- data.frame(hittitle = c("HIT title 1", "HIT title 2", "HIT title 3"),
                    hitvariable = c("HIT text 1", "HIT text 2", "HIT text 3"), 
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    BulkCreateFromTemplate(template = temp,
                           input = a,
                           annotation = paste("Bulk From Template", Sys.Date()),
                           title = "Categorize an image",
                           description = "Categorize this image",
                           reward = ".05",
                           expiration = seconds(days = 4),
                           duration = seconds(minutes = 5),
                           auto.approval.delay = seconds(days = 1),
                           keywords = "categorization, image, moderation, category")
```

Error I m getting while running the template is as follow:
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2011-11-11/HTMLQuestion.xsd'>450': Invalid argument

```
#tempalte I am using is:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'/>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/mturk-public/externalHIT_v1.js'></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form name='mturk_form' method='post' id='mturk_form' action='https://www.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit'>
  <input type='hidden' value='' name='assignmentId' id='assignmentId'/>
  <h1>${hittitle}</h1>
  <p>${hitvariable}</p>
  <p>What do you think?</p>
  <p><textarea name='comment' cols='80' rows='3'></textarea></p>
  <p><input type='submit' id='submitButton' value='Submit' /></p></form>
  <script language='Javascript'>turkSetAssignmentID();</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
temp <- system.file("template.html", package = "MTurkR")
```

`"template.html"` is not a file installed with MTurkR so `system.file()` is not appropriate here. If you're trying to access a file called `"template.html"` in your working directory (or somewhere else on your computer), you just need to do the following:

```
BulkCreateFromTemplate(template = "template.html", ...
```

along with the other options passed to `BulkCreateFromTemplate()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help